# Can one reverse left axis in vis.js Graph2d?

Tags: javascript, graph, vis.js

I need to show position of a song in a chart over some date range.

Can I do it with `vis.js` without using 1/y?

Comment: What do you mean with 1/y? vis.js can be used to visualize a lot of things. If you can refine your question we may be able to help you.

Comment: Uh, I was wrong about `1/y`. I ended up using `-y` values to invert the y-axis

Comment: If someone could show an example of _song position in chart_ graph, that would be great

Comment: http://visjs.org/graph2d_examples.html#allExamples you can see lot of examples. I'm sure your song position in chart will fit in somewhere.